# 'Invalid postback or callback argument' error on simulated POST request in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, webrequest

I would like to use the `WebRequest` class to crawl some data.

I use the get request to access the site, and then use the regular expression to get to `VIEWSTATE`, `PREVIOUSPAGE` and `EVENTVALIDATION`..., and then use the post request related pages, get the error message, as follows:

> 505|error|500|Invalid postback or callback argument. Event validation is enabled using  in configuration or <%@ Page EnableEventValidation="true" %> in a page. For security purposes, this feature verifies that arguments to postback or callback events originate from the server control that originally rendered them. If the data is valid and expected, use the ClientScriptManager.RegisterForEventValidation method in order to register the postback or callback data for validation.

Where is the problem?

Comment: I would assume that the problem is in the request you are posting back to the server. This request does not match the data that the code is expecting from the page, and so is throwing the error as a security precaution. I assume that  this is a site under your control?

Comment: I put all the required form data back, using the code。And I wrote myself a simple asp.net site that contains ajax cascading menu，Through the request to the data request to viewstate, and then post to the server, you can get a options of second drop。

Comment: Your comment doesn't make any sense to me, sorry